# How to define a private member behavior, as a method or property? C#

Tags: c#, methods, properties

I have a object which is used in another context and I want to validate if a private member is null or empty (which is exposed by its property). It would be better to declare inside the class of the object to encapsulate the behavior instead of doing the validation at every moment where is used, but the question is if better to do it as a property or method?

```
public bool HasValue()
{
     return String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.privateMember) == false;
}
```

or

```
public bool HasValue
{
     get
     {
          return String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.privateMember) == false;
     }
}
```

Example of usage:

```
if(myObject.HasValue()){
}
```

or

```
if(myObject.HasValue){
}
```

What is better? Any impact or it just visual?

Comment: either one is fine.  They're essentially the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well that certainly *feels* more like a property to me than a method - and it's certainly in-keeping with things like [`Nullable<T>.HasValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sksw8094.aspx).

Other differences to consider:

- You can generally bind against properties but not methods; not sure you'd want to bind against this anyway
- You can't use properties for method group conversions (unfortunately) to create delegates
- Properties are automatically evaluated when debugging; methods aren't

There shouldn't be any performance impact.

As an aside, rather than comparing against `false`, I'd write the implementation as:

```
return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(privateMember);
```

Comment: +1 for the nice write up. Also, @Maximus Decimus , Read this article in msdn for deeper understanding: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229054(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't have many impact for the compiler its just visual but i prefer the second one i'm always doing hate the () :)

Answer (score 0):

[`System.Nullable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) uses the property [`HasValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sksw8094.aspx), so I would use the same approach for consistency with the .NET Framework.

Comment: It was an example. I'm trying to validate my own field.